# Help on proving inductive conclusion for a summation identity

Tags: induction

I am running into trouble for proving the inductive conclusion for the proof of the following statement:

For all non-negative integers $n$,
$$\sum_{r=0}^n r\binom{n}{r}=\frac{1}{2}n\sum_{r=0}^n \binom{n}{r}$$
Induction on n

Base case $(n=0)$: 
$$\sum_{r=0}^0 r\binom{0}{r}=0\qquad\frac{1}{2}(0)\sum_{r=0}^0 \binom{0}{r}1=0\qquad 0=0$$
Therefore true when $(n=0)$

Inductive hypothesis: Assume 
$$\sum_{r=0}^k r\binom{k}{r}=\frac{1}{2}k\sum_{r=0}^k\binom{k}{r}$$
for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ where $k\ge 0$

Inductive conclusion: Want to prove
$$\sum_{r=0}^{k+1}r\binom{k+1}{r}=\frac{1}{2}(k+1)\sum_{r=0}^{k+1}\binom{k+1}{r}$$
So
$$\sum_{r=0}^{k+1} r\binom{k+1}{r}=\sum_{r=0}^{k} r\binom{k+1}{r}+(k+1)\binom{k+1}{k+1}=\sum_{r=0}^{k} r\binom{k+1}{r}+(k+1)$$
So yeah, this is where I'm stuck. Any help?

Comment: While you can probably finish this argument in some way, here's a shorter one: First prove that $r \dbinom{n}{r} = n \dbinom{n-1}{r-1}$. Now what do you know about $\sum\limits_{r=0}^n \dbinom{n-1}{r-1}$ ?

Comment: You will need to write $\binom{k+1}r$ in terms of $\binom{k}{{\rm something}}$.  What does Pascal's triangle tell you about this?